# How to check if user has given camera or location permissions (android) UNITY

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, android-permissions

I really struggle with this since a while :( as I need an **solution that works within UNITY3D.**

**I need to check if the user has given the permission to access the Android device camera** (and location on a second level).

Normally the app start by **asking for this permissions at launch, but if the user denies the access** for the camera I need to know and check that later.

Otherwise the user could hit the camera UI button I made and try to access the camera via webcamtexture... and that leads into a **crash of the app.**

**Since Android API 23 you cannot ignore or already grant permissions by changing the android manifest** like I tried after reading several posts about that.

Thank's to everyone who has an idea to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this library: https://github.com/sanukin39/UniAndroidPermission

In that library I got these methods to check and request Permission.

```
 public static void requestPermission(String permissionStr){
        if(!hasPermission(permissionStr)) {
            UnityPlayer.currentActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{permissionStr}, 0);
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasPermission(String permissionStr) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            return true;
        }
        Context context = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getApplicationContext();
        return context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permissionStr) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you so much @Bhuvanesh Bs!! This solves the issues I had. Great to have such good help in here. :)

Comment: Thanks, this lib helped when nothing could. I had all permissions granted even when checking final manifest in apk, but the app never asked for them. This could override them somehow